# Can I make npm install follow a certain package.json format?

Tags: node.js, npm

When you install an npm package and use the `--save`, `--save-dev` or `--save-optional` options to write the package into your package.json file in the appropriate dependencies property, the entire file appears to be rewritten with 2-space indentation:

```
$ cat package.json
{
    "name": "my-package"
}

$ npm install --save another-package && cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "dependencies": {
    "another-package": "~0.1.5"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make npm follow the existing format, or to specifiy a custom format (e.g. 4-space indentation) for the package.json file?

I can't find anything in the [npm options documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After digging through the [npm source](https://github.com/isaacs/npm), it unfortunately appears the answer to my question is definitely "no". When `npm install` is executed with one of the "save" options, the [following happens](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/36a412d0eb065cdd1e916f6b001c098ff5c7efc3/lib/install.js#L355):

```
fs.readFile(saveTarget, function (er, data) {
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8"))
  } catch (ex) {
    er = ex
  }
  // ...
  data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + "\n"
  fs.writeFile(saveTarget, data, function (er) {
    cb(er, installed, tree, pretty)
  })
})
```

The important line is the call to `JSON.stringify`. When invoking `stringify` with the third argument, the returned string indentation is formatted with the specified number of spaces.

Since there is no way to customise the value used by npm internally, this behaviour is currently non-configurable.

Comment: Npm does accept pull requests, though. It would be great to be able to plug a formatter for all npm commands that write `package.json`, so we'd be able to pick, say, `require('format-json').diffy` instead of its current hard-coded stringifier.

Comment: IIRC, I probed for whether one would be accepted, and got a firm no, and left it at that. (So: not from me, but maybe from other folks.)

Comment: try a pull request to io.js . They have open governance policy mind u :)

Answer (score 4):

> Fixed in [64b67f0](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/64b67f00) and npm 5...

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4718#issuecomment-307142397

[image]