# How Can I Prevent npm from Reformating package.json When Versioning?

Tags: node.js, npm, whitespace

I am one of those crazy dev who likes to format my JS and JSON with tabs instead of spaces — stone me later. When I increment my package.json version with `npm version <newversion>`, my package.json reverts to spaces. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571329/can-i-make-npm-install-follow-a-certain-package-json-format

Answer (score -1):

This situation is finally solved in a popular new alternative node package manager called Yarn:

https://yarnpkg.com

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn

If your `package.json` file is indented with tabs, it'll respect that even when you install new packages or increment the version number, etc. It's been really nice to use so far.